Converting a USB flash drive to a part of the phone's storage without booting the system?
Connect the usb flash drive with otg to the phone and make it a part of the phone's internal storage without booting the system and without booting the Rom.
It is possible or not

Not on a bootloader locked device.

Not possible at all
